# Plot categorical scatterplot in seaborn or matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe

```
   it, A   B   C   D
0  10, aa  mn  cd  kk
1  100, ab  cd  wc  ll
2  1000, wc  cd  mn  sf
3  10000, ll  ll  kk  mn
4  100000, wc  kk  mn  cd
5  1000000, aa  ll  we  sf
6  10000000, ss  aa  ss  kk
```

created as

```
options = ["ab", "cd", "bb", "aa", "we", "ss", "kk", "mn", "re", "wc", "ll", "sf"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
for i, it in enumerate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]):
    row = [10**i, random.sample(options, 1)[0], random.sample(options, 1)[0], 
           random.sample(options, 1)[0], random.sample(options, 1)[0]]
    df.loc[i] = row
```

The goal is to create a scatterplot where y axis are unique values from a dataframe in **sorted order** e.g options and a-axis corresponds to column `it`.
Now depending on whether data belongs to column `A, B, C,` or `D` I want to color scatter-dots differently and specify a legend. So I know what class a dot comes from.

How do I do it in seaborn or matplotlib?

The way I am doing it in matplotlib is

```
iters = list(range(df.shape[0]))
x, y = sort(iters, df["A"])
plt.scatter(x, y, color="red")
x, y = sort(iters, df["B"])
plt.scatter(x, y, color="blue")
...
```

but that does not sort the entire y-axis, only labels that belong to separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try stack the data, convert to categorical with given order, sort and plot:

```
s = df.stack() 

s = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(s, categories=options, ordered=True),
              index=s.index)

sns.scatterplot(data=s.sort_values().reset_index(name='value'),
                x='level_0', y='value', hue='level_1'
               )
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Update**: if you have a column `xvalue` and only care for some columns `['A','B','C','D']`, use `melt` instead of `stack`:

```
s = df.melt(id_vars='xvalue', 
            value_vars=['A','B','C','D'],
            value_name='value',
            var_name='column')
s['value'] = pd.Categorical(s['value'], categories=options, ordered=True)

sns.scatterplot(data=s.sort_values('value'),
                x='xvalue', y='value', hue='column'
               )
```

Comment: But that does not look sorted! x-axis is supposed to be y-axis, but thats not a big issue.
The problem is that x-axis is not sorted, at least for matplotlib one

Comment: @YohanRoth I missed the `options` part. See updated answer.

Comment: so your solution does not work in my case, it's my fault, I did not specify the problem correctly. in addition to A, B, C, D column I have another column that specifies x-axis values that are not just row iters (they have large gaps like 1, 10, 1000, 10000) etc. Could you show me how to modify the answer to accomodate this? Anyways I will accept it! I updated the problem

Comment: I get 
ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (28)

for  s['value'] = pd.Categorical(s, categories=options, ordered=True)

Comment: s.shape  (28, 3)
pd.Categorical  (3,)

Comment: @YohanRoth should be `pd.Categorical(s['value'],...)`. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you! Different but problem related question (maybe you can help) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64845266/assign-different-markers-size-borders-and-opacity-in-seaborn-scatterplot