# Assign different markers, size, borders and opacity in seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe

```
   xvalue, A   B   C   D
0  10, aa  mn  cd  kk
1  20, ab  cd  wc  ll
2  30, wc  cd  mn  sf
3  40, ll  ll  kk  mn
4  50, wc  kk  mn  cd
5  60, aa  ll  we  sf
6  70, ss  aa  ss  kk
```

Code to create it

```
options = ["ab", "cd", "bb", "aa", "we", "ss", "kk", "mn", "re", "wc", "ll", "sf"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
for i, it in enumerate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]):
    row = [10*i, random.sample(options, 1)[0], random.sample(options, 1)[0], 
           random.sample(options, 1)[0], random.sample(options, 1)[0]]
    df.loc[i] = row
```

And plotting is done

```
s = df.melt(id_vars='xvalue', 
            value_vars=['A','B','C','D'],
            value_name='value',
            var_name='column')
s['value'] = pd.Categorical(s['value'], categories=options, ordered=True)

sns.scatterplot(data=s.sort_values('value'), x='xvalue', y='value', hue='column')
```

Now the question -- how do I assign different styles to scatter-dots that belong to different classes (defined by columns, e.g `A, B, C, D`). FOr example I want class A to be marker "P", B to be marker "p", C to be marker "v". Same I want to define alpha (opacity), border line, specify color etc.

In matplotlib I would do

```
plt.scatter(x, y, color="blue", label="A", alpha=0.8, s=80, marker="p")
```

But that would explicitly create a different plot on a graph with its own params. Right now I don't know how to deal with different classes within "one plot".

I also tried

```
markers = {"A": "s", "B": "X", "C": "p", "D":"o"}
sns.scatterplot(data=s.sort_values('value'), x='xvalue', y='value', hue='column', markers=markers)
```

But it gave no effect.

EDIT: in order to apply different markers I should specify style="column", but if I try

```
sizes = {"A":100, "B": 120, "C": 150, "D":200}
sns.scatterplot(data=s.sort_values('value'), x='xvalue', y='value', hue='column', markers=markers, s=sizes)
```

It does not work

Comment: You can change markers in different classes with `style='column'`, but you can't do it individually, such as transparency and color.

Comment: @r-beginners if I do style='column" I can apply different markers, but not different sizes, alphas, borders, etc. How do I achieve those ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to replace the strings/values in `options` with the enumeration:

```
opt_dict = {opt:i for i,opt in enumerate(options)}

markers = {"A": "s", "B": "X", "C": "p", "D":"o"}
sizes = {"A":100, "B": 120, "C": 150, "D":200}
alphas = {'A':0.2, 'B':0.3, 'C':0.6, 'D':0.8}
col_list = ['A','B','C','D']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6))
for col in col_list:
    ax.scatter(df['xvalue'], df[col].map(opt_dict), 
               marker=markers[col],
               s=sizes[col],
               alpha=alphas[col],
               label=col)
    
ax.set_yticks(range(len(options)))
ax.set_yticklabels(options)
ax.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this approach removes sorted order, unfortunately!

Comment: @YohanRoth y axis shows the correct order doesn’t it?

Comment: @YohanRoth don’t you want to plot them in the order of `options`?

Comment: Sorry if this wasnt clear, but no, I want "options" to be on y-axis but in sorted order.
I do now
cats = sorted(s["value"].unique())
s['value'] = pd.Categorical(s['value'], categories=cats, ordered=True)